# Using like in group by MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to use the logic similar to 'like' in group by.

For example, data would be:

```
John1 
John2 
John3
Steve1
Steve2
```

I want the output like:

```
John 3
```

I have searched about the solutions but I got with the static text. I will be passing the parameter value dynamically in 'having' clause. (like here I will pass 'John').

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the O/P `John 3`, 3 is the number of occurrence of `John`?

Comment: yes. 3 is number of occurance of prefix 'John'.

Comment: Can you give us more information about your table and data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for something that is `LIKE` John, then you use

```
SELECT yourColumn 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourColumn LIKE '%John%';
```

That is the way to use sql.

If you want to group your data you can still group it after filtering via `WHERE`.

```
SELECT yourColumn, SUM(aggregatedColumn) 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourColumn LIKE '%John%' 
GROUP BY yourColumn;
```

And after that, you can use `HAVING` to filter by some aggragate.

```
SELECT yourColumn, SUM(aggregatedColumn) 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourColumn LIKE '%John%' 
GROUP BY yourColumn
HAVING SUM(aggregatedColumn) > 12;
```

(I think) You are looking for a query like this:

```
SELECT yourColumn, MAX(occurrences)
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourColumn LIKE '%John%' 
GROUP BY yourColumn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is like so:

yourtable:

```
yourfield
John1 
John2 
John3
Steve1
Steve2
```

Then you could use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` in a sort of brutish way:

```
SELECT
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(yourfield,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','') AS NAME,
COUNT(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(yourfield,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')) AS NAME_COUNT
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(yourfield,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')
```

Output:

```
NAME    NAME_COUNT
John    3
Steve   2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64506f/1/0

With `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(yourfield,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','') AS NAME,
COUNT(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(yourfield,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')) AS NAME_COUNT
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourfield LIKE '%john%'
GROUP BY Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(yourfield,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','')
```